# Running a Python app on a remote server and displaying the output files

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a Python 2.7 script at https://github.com/jhsu802701/dopplervalueinvesting .  When I run the screen.py script locally, the end result is a new screen-output sub-directory (within the root directory) and a results.csv file within it.

What I'm trying to do is put this script on a remote server, run this screen.py script every night, and make the results.csv file publicly readable.

I've tried to do this on Google App Engine, but I can't get it to work.  The Google App Engine tutorial revolves around trying to dynamically create a web site, and I haven't been able to figure out how to make anything other than an index.html file in the root directory work.  HOW DO I MAKE OTHER FILES PUBLICLY READABLE?

Is Google App Engine the way to go, or am I barking up the wrong tree?  I understand that another route is using WebFaction, a web hosting provider that offers a whole Linux system.  (Running my app on my current web host, MDDHosting, is not an option because lxml is not available without a much more costly VPS.)

In summary, my questions are:

1. How do I run my Python script in Google App Engine and make the output results.csv file publicly available?
2. If Google App Engine isn't the solution for me, should I use WebFaction?  (I already tried Heroku, and it didn't work for me.)
3. What are my other options?

I'm willing to pay for a solution, but only if I get web hosting as well.  (I'm not willing to pay for MDDHosting for my dopplervalueinvesting.com web site AND another host for running my script.)

Comment: with google app engine you can't write to the file system, you have to use the [datastore API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/) to store content. I didn't read your whole code, maybe you need to adapt other parts too to use [app-engine's API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/libraries) if wou want to use that.

Answer (score 0):

I think GAE should be good for what you want, but you may need to work differently because, as a comment pointed out, you can't write to the file system but have to use the datastore instead.

So you need in your app.yaml list of handlers, something like

```
- url: /results.csv
  script: deliver_results_file.py
- url: /screen
  login: admin
  script: screen.py
```

screen.py needs to save the results to the datastore in some convenient format. deliver_results_file.py then queries the datastore, and if the results are not already in CSV format then it converts them accordingly. It then writes the formatted data directly to the output (usually using `self.response.out.write` within a webapp request handler) as if it was a dynamically generated webpage.

Finally you want to schedule it to run once a night - I believe this is possible using [cron jobs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron).